# How Do I Change The Time Out Settings?

Tags: display, 18.10

I like to use my laptop frequently on my father's Television when he's at work to watch something over the Internet like Crunchyroll, and when I wash the Dishes I like to listen to music on Spotify but I've noticed that it keeps timing out, is there a way to change this. I'm using Ubuntu 18.10 Cosmic Cuddlefish, it's really annoying trying to listen to music when it keeps timing out like that.

Comment: what do you mean by 'timing out'?

Comment: When you leave the computer or laptop idle for a while and it goes to sleep when your not around it and you have to touch something on the computer to wake it up.

Comment: That would be in the settings power option, top right corner of screen!

Comment: That helped a little, what I did was go to the thing with a bunch of dots, sorry lol I don't know what it's called, and typed in power settings, when I clicked on settings from the top right corner it was just showing me the display settings instead. But thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the `Show Applications` button and then type `settings` and go to the `power` section and click to modify the settings there to look like the image below:

[image]

Change the settings for `Blank screen`, `Suspend & Power Buttons` to look like image above.

Comment: Oh thank you for helping me that really did help